# DataNucleus: which version runs on java 1.7?

Tags: android, jpa, java-8, datanucleus

Trying DataNucleus 5.1.1 on android, got runtime error:

```
      Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/LocalDate;

at org.datanucleus.ClassConstants.<clinit>(ClassConstants.java:72) ~[na:na]

at org.datanucleus.util.Localiser.<clinit>(Localiser.java:87) ~[na:na]

at org.datanucleus.util.Localiser.registerBundle(Localiser.java:100) ~[na:na]

at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.<clinit>(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:99) ~[na:na]

at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:104) ~[na:0.0]

at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79) ~[na:0.0]
```

The class java.time.LocaleDate is available on Java 1.8. 
Does android 7 (API 24) support Java 8 except some special cases, right?

Comment: Just because there's a Java library available, doesn't naturally mean it will work in Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to have done much research to that question. If I go to [this page on their website](http://www.datanucleus.org/documentation/products.html) it shows that the last version that supports JRE v1.7 is DataNucleus v4.x. This is likely because JRE 1.7 was end-of-life **a long time ago** and many other software projects have not supported it for some time with their latest releases.

Comment: Tried 4.1.x from maven repository, there are issues with enhancer: can not deal with generics interface. Have to give up 4.x. Thanks.

Comment: Strange that there are no issues in their issue tracker.